# How can I type hint enum values in python, bounded to some protocol

Tags: python, enums, mypy

I'm trying to type hint enum values, so that each value is bounded to some protocol.
The desired typing error is a warning on enum creation, not on calling.

Minimum working example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import typing as t
from enum import Enum


class Viewable(t.Protocol):
    def view(self):
        ...


class MyNumber:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value

    def view(self):
        print(self.value)


class MyString:
    def __init__(self, value: str):
        self.value = value

    def view(self):
        print(self.value)


one = MyNumber(1)
two = MyNumber(2)
three = MyString("three")
four = 4


T = t.TypeVar("T", bound=Viewable)


class MyEnum(Enum, t.Generic[T]):
    ONE = one
    TWO = two
    THREE = three
    FOUR = four                   # <--- I want mypy to complain here, as four is not viewable


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyEnum.ONE.value.view()
    MyEnum.TWO.value.view()
    MyEnum.THREE.value.view()
    MyEnum.FOUR.value.view()       # <--- mypy complains about this
```

Ideally, I would not want to repeat the typing annotation for each value (which does not work for enum, as types are `Literal`.

I'm not sure if Enum is the right tool for this, what i'm looking is for a simple interface that works as a dict, but with fixed keys that can be accessed by attribute.

Comment: Without a mypy plugin, mypy can't complain about the assignment statement `FOUR = four`, because it's not annotated (so it just infers the type by the r-value). You say: "...does not work for enum, as types are `Literal`"; this isn't true until outside of the enum class context, where is when you access the enum members (`MyEnum.FOUR -> Literal[MyEnum.FOUR]`); during the assignment in the enum, they're not `Literal`s.

Answer (score 2):

Non-annotated assignment statements can't be type-checked, so mypy will never complain about the statement `FOUR = four`. If you don't want to repeatedly type `FOUR: Viewable = four`, you should instead use a mypy plugin to make an implicit annotation for you. Here's a basic implementation:

1. First, the result we're looking for:

   ```py
   """MY_PACKAGE/MY_MODULE.py"""

   ...

   class MyEnum(Enum):  # Don't co-inherit from `t.Generic[T]`
       ONE = one
       TWO = two
       THREE = three
       FOUR = four  # mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "Viewable") [assignment]
   ```
2. Project structure:

   ```
   MY_PROJECT/
       mypy.ini
       mypy_plugin/
           plugin_entry.py
       MY_PACKAGE/
           __init__.py
           MY_MODULE.py
   ```

   - Contents of `mypy.ini`:

     ```ini
     [mypy]
     plugins = mypy_plugin/plugin_entry.py
     ```
   - Contents of `mypy_plugin/plugin_entry.py`

     ```py
     from __future__ import annotations

     import typing as t
     import mypy.plugin
     import mypy.traverser

     if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
         import collections.abc as cx
         import mypy.nodes


     class Plugin(mypy.plugin.Plugin):

         # This hook method is chosen as it directly allows you to compare full names 
         # of classes to delegate a hook - we're not actually changing class MRO here.
         def get_customize_class_mro_hook(
             self, fullname: str
         ) -> cx.Callable[[mypy.plugin.ClassDefContext], None] | None:

             if fullname == "MY_PACKAGE.MY_MODULE.MyEnum":
                 return hook

             return None


     def hook(ctx: mypy.plugin.ClassDefContext) -> None:
         annotator: EnumAnnotator = EnumAnnotator(ctx=ctx)
         ctx.cls.accept(annotator)  # Recursively traverse the class AST


     class EnumAnnotator(mypy.traverser.TraverserVisitor):
         ctx: mypy.plugin.ClassDefContext

         def __init__(self, ctx: mypy.plugin.ClassDefContext) -> None:
             self.ctx = ctx

         def visit_assignment_stmt(self, o: mypy.nodes.AssignmentStmt) -> None:
             # `o.type` is the type annotation of the l-value's assignment.
             # If there's no type annotation, add `Viewable` as the annotation.
             if o.type is None:
                 o.type = self.ctx.api.named_type("MY_PACKAGE.MY_MODULE.Viewable")


     def plugin(version: str) -> type[mypy.plugin.Plugin]:
         return Plugin
     ```

You can now run `mypy MY_PACKAGE/MY_MODULE.py` to see the linting errors:

```bash
$ mypy MY_PACKAGE/MY_MODULE.py
MY_PACKAGE/MY_MODULE.py:39: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "Viewable")  [assignment]
```